# Why do I get "Unresolved reference" for a class that the project does allow to reach?

Tags: android

### Background

I've made a tiny library that I've published on Github, which allows you to have auto-switching of texts every X ms :

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutomatedTextSwitcher

The project has a library and a sample modules. The sample uses the library, and the library has a single class (currently), called "AutomatedTextSwitcher".

### The problem

For some reason, the project doesn't seem to be able to be built, as the IDE shows these errors:

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\AutomatedTextSwitcher\app\src\main\java\com\example\user\automated_text_switcher\MainActivity.kt:
>   (5, 47): Unresolved reference: AutomatedTextSwitcher
>        C:\Users\User\Desktop\AutomatedTextSwitcher\app\src\main\java\com\example\user\automated_text_switcher\MainActivity.kt:
>   (21, 35): Unresolved reference: setTextsToShow

### What I've tried

The errors appear here even though when I use CTRL+mouse-left-click, the IDE reaches to the correct place in code.

The class exists, and the function of `setTextsToShow` also exists and is public.

Copying the code to an existing project seem to have it work fine.

Since I suspect this is a bug on the IDE, I've also reported about this [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112765998).

### The question

How come I have this issue? Why does it occur? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you switch from a beta ide(ex 3.2) to a stable ide (ex 3.1.X) or downgraded your ide

Comment: @MohammadTabbara I tried now on stable version of the IDE (3.1.4) . Still same issue.  Also tried a stable version of gradle plugin in the build.gradle file , and this gave another build error, of "Configuration on demand"

Comment: U didn't answer the question. I asked if you switched IDE or downgraded ide since this bug can be because  of them. for example IDE 3.1.4 supports  1.2.50 as max for kotlin while your using 1.2.61.

Comment: @MohammadTabbara I already wrote you that I tried. I tried to downgrade to see if it helps. It doesn't. I tried both canary and stable versions of the IDE

Comment: I draged the AutomatedTextSwitcher.kt file to the app module and everything worked fine but when i draged it back into the module i got the following conflicts https://pastebin.com/vEvjgNzA Sorry if it isn't well formated wish it can help you. Last line said will not be accessible in module library

Comment: @MohammadTabbara As I wrote, when I copy it all to existing project, it worked fine. I don't know why you got a different issue. I want to know why there are issues, and how to solve them